# Run function in a loop with length defined by a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas

How can I run a function passing values from a list?

I have this list

```
keywords = ['car','water','2 bottles']
```

and a function defined as follows:

```
def my_func(param):
    b = df.loc[df['Field'].str.contains(param), 'User'].tolist()
    print (f'\nThe item "{param}" was bought by in User: ', b)
    return b
```

Currently I am doing it manually:

```
buyer= my_func('car')
buyer= my_func('water')
buyer= my_func('2 bottles')
```

However, I would like to run the function and printing the results by iterating param over the list keywords.
Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
def my_func(param):
    b = df.loc[df['Field'].str.contains(param), 'User'].tolist()
    print (f'\nThe item "{param}" was bought by in User: ', b)
    return b

keywords = ['car','water','2 bottles']

buyers = []

for key in keywords:
    buyers.append(my_func(key))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do regex

```
b = df.loc[df['Field'].str.contains('|'.join(keywords)), 'User'].tolist()
```